# Modify html attributes in Webrat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrat

Can I modify the html in a page using Webrat?

To be specific, I want to change the name attribute in an input in a form before I submit the form.

Comment: What do you mean by plain Cucumber? Racktest? Cucumber isn't a driver.

Comment: I think a better question is "Why?" :)

Comment: @Andrey - you're right, sorry: Webrat.  Stefan - I'll worry about the why, thanks :)